# NameError after declaring variable in class

Tags: python

I was simulating a deck of cards where a random card from the draw_pile list is returned and then removed from the draw_pile and appending it in the discard_pile.

```
class Deck:

    draw_pile = ["example_1", "example_2", "example_3"]
    discard_pile = []

    def draw(self):
        card = random.choice(draw_pile)
        draw_pile.remove(card)
        discard_pile.append(card)
        return card

example_deck = Deck()
print(example_deck.draw())
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
card = random.choice(draw_pile)
NameError: name 'draw_pile' is not defined"
```

Comment: use `card=random.choice(self.draw_pile)`, `draw_pile` is a variable of the class, so you need to use `self.draw_pile` within the class to access the value

Comment: Inside `draw`, everywhere you have `draw_pile` and `discard_pile`, you mean `self.draw_pile` and `self.discard_pile` respectively.

Comment: You're referencing `self` in `def draw()`; your vars need to be members of `self` as well or defined/initialized within the function.

Comment: Use an `__init__` method to make your piles rather than putting them in the class definition (access using `self.pile` as others have said).

Answer (score 2):

A Python class does not create a new scope for the lookup algorithm. Inside `draw`, when a local definition of `draw_pile` cannot be found, Python next looks at the next enclosing scope, which is the module-level scope, not the enclosing class definition.

To access the class attribute, you need to use either the class name

```
def draw(self) :
    card = random.choice(deck.draw_pile)
    deck.draw_pile.remove(card)
    deck.discard_pile.append(card)
    return card
```

or access it indirectly via `self`; if no instance attribute named `draw_pile` is found, Python next looks at the class attributes for the type of `self`:

```
def draw(self) :
    card = random.choice(self.draw_pile)
    self.draw_pile.remove(card)
    self.discard_pile.append(card)
    return card
```

Arguably, it is cleaner to be specific about where `draw_pile` and `discard_pile` are coming from, and use the class name directly. Using `self` requires you to know more about which classes `self` has in its MRO.

Also, unless `deck` is never intended to have more than a single instance, both `draw_pile` and `discard_pile` should be instance variables anyway, and thus *must* be accessed via `self`:

```
class Deck :
    def __init__(self):
        self.draw_pile = ["exmample_1", "example_2", "example_3"]
        self.discard_pile = [""]

    def draw(self) :
        card = random.choice(self.draw_pile)
        self.draw_pile.remove(card)
        self.discard_pile.append(card)
        return card

example_deck = Deck()
print(Deck.draw())
```